# How to set dynamically props key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have props with value status, key, value and I am able to get the value using

```
this.props. status,
this.props.key,
this.props.value
```

But I am looking for a solution that 
I have to dynamically pass the props key
For eg:

```
dynamicFunction(variable)
{
let tempValue= this.props.{here I have to pass value}  
console.log(tempValue) 
}
```

if this.props.key value is true then console have to print true
Any solutions?

Comment: this.props[variable] should work

Answer (score 0):

Each object property can be accessed like you access and Array, with ['property'].

So you can use a variable containing the property you want to access and create something "dynamic".

```
const value = 'key';
let tempValue = this.props[value];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pass the value using the parameter 'variable' then this might help you.

```
this.props. status,
this.props.key,
this.props.value

dynamicFunction(variable)
{
let tempValue= this.props[variable];  // here if you call this function with 'status' as parameter it will work.
console.log(tempValue) ;
}
```